# Java: How to compare between the user and the real answer and ensure it's grammatically correct using String?

Tags: java, compare, grammar, compareto

I am trying to build an English Idiom game by using Java programming. My understanding to create this game so far is that every English idiom is already fixed, and have it's own meaning (e.g - "Last Straw" which means "The final problem in series of problem") which,  also could be vary.

I want to create a game that could cater this. A user will be asked about an idiom meaning, give their answer in the text field and the algorithm will check it either the answer is correct or not. But here's my dilemma;

1.) The user might give their answer, but the answer is too ambiguous/vague and wasn't exactly the SAME with the real answer planned. I wanted to use keyword comparison method for this, but is it really going to SOLVE THE PROBLEM? Which leads me to a second problem...

2.) How to ensure that the word, the answer prompt by the user is GRAMMATICALLY correct in English language as well? I mean they can write something like "problem final" and if I put the keyword comparison earlier, it will check the answer as a right answer, right? Despite   it doesn't make any sense grammatically.

So, are there any suggestion/ideas on how to make of these two problem? Were my solution for the first (1) question acceptable and the second (2) question possible? Because I seriously don't know what do now...

Comment: Well, allowing the user to type in anything would mean that your program have to actually understand what the user typed. That's a very hard topic and it's not related to Java but general computer science, there must be thousands of articles doing that. For simplification I would create a game as a multiple choice, which is ofc not the same game but if the idea is to learn programming rather than researching a huge topic it might be more feasible.

Comment: This is going to be a LOT of work, probably too much to really want to do it...

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of aspects for this topic. Since this game includes idioms and checking the grammer, there are multiple implementations you may need.
For the grammer part you can try [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/). It is very nice well documented and may be suitable for your need.